# unbale to replace method in python

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, str-replace

My problem is that I have to replcae the value in the remarked column and store it all in a new varble.

EXMP: - Wherever there is "True" in the Remark column, that "Data" gets updated.
I have tried many times but I am not able to get many errors.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NOTES': ["PREPAID_HOME_SCREEN_MAMO","SCREEN_MAMO",
                              "> Unable to connect internet>4G Compatible>Set",
                              "No>Not Barred>Active>No>Available>Others>",
                              "Internet Not Working>>>Unable To Connect To"]})

df1['remark']= df1['NOTES'].str.contains('Internet')|df1['NOTES'].str.contains('MAMO')

df2 = df1['remark'].replace("True","Data")
```

my Try :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzaPy.png)

Comment: Print `df2`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are trying to do a string replace on a boolean type.

Try casting the column to a string first and then apply you replace method on that column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NOTES': ["PREPAID_HOME_SCREEN_MAMO", "SCREEN_MAMO",
                              "> Unable to connect internet>4G Compatible>Set",
                              "No>Not Barred>Active>No>Available>Others>",
                              "Internet Not Working>>>Unable To Connect To"]})

df1['remark'] = df1['NOTES'].str.contains('Internet') | df1['NOTES'].str.contains('MAMO')


df2 = df1['remark'].astype(str).replace("True", "Data")
```

Comment: Thanks .  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NOTES': ["PREPAID_HOME_SCREEN_MAMO", "SCREEN_MAMO",
                              "> Unable to connect internet>4G Compatible>Set",
                              "No>Not Barred>Active>No>Available>Others>",
                              "Internet Not Working>>>Unable To Connect To"]})

df1['remark'] = df1['NOTES'].str.contains('Internet') | df1['NOTES'].str.contains('MAMO')

df1['remark']=df1['remark'].astype(str).replace("True", "Data")

df1